# Parent element in css

Tags: html, css

What's a difference in selector's pattern `E * F` and `E F`? Both `E * F` and `E F` applying appropriate style to `F` which is child of `E`. Consider HTML:

```
<div id= "parent">
    <div id="subparent">
        <div id="subsubparent">
            <input type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and corresponding css

```
#parent, #subparent{
    padding:20px;
    background:green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
#subparent{
    background:black;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
#subsubparent{
    background: blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
div[id="parent"] input{
    width:50px;

}
```

Where `div[id="parent"] input` applying appropriate style to input which is child of `div#parent`. I my case `div#subparent` is child of `div#parent`, `div#subsubparent` is child of `div#subparent` and `input` is child of `div#subsubparent`. Hence `input` is child of `div#parent`.

In the case of `E * F`. `E *` matches any element which child of `E` and hence `E * F` mathces `F` element which child of `E`.

Comment: as evidence http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's a difference in selector's pattern `E * F` and `E F`?

`E F` matches any `F` which is a descendant if `E`. The selector also matches if `F` is a child of `E`.

`E * F` matches any `F` which is a descendant of any descendant (`*`) of `E`. The selectors does **not** match if `F` is a child of `E`.

Example:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="baz">
         <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`.foo .bar` matches all `.bar` elements inside `.foo`.

`.foo * .bar` only matches the `.bar` element inside `.baz`.

---

Another way to look at it:
`E F` could also be written as `E * F, E > F`, hence `E * F` is only a *subset* of the what `E F` selects.

Answer (score 1):

Selectors are explained here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html

```
E F
```

means all F children of E.

```
E * F
```

means all F grand children of E. That is, F cannot be a direct child of E. That being said, it can be at any level below the children of E.

Another precision:

```
E > F
```

means F but only if a direct child of E.

Comment: *"means all F children of E"* Be carful with terminology. A child is only a *direct descendant*. The space is the *descendant selector*, it selects *descendants* (which includes children). It's like in real life: The child of your child is your grand-child (or descendant), not your child.

Answer (score 0):

`E * F` matches descendent `F` that is a descendent of `*` *(anything)*, which is a descendent of `E`, while `E F` matches descendent `F` of `E`. `E * F` does not match it's child descendent, only descendents of its child. Use `>` for child.

Comment: Not child, descendant. There is a reason why `E F` is called *descendant selector* and `E > F` *child selector*.